Gradle Build failed with React Native apk app build
I ran the command eas -p android to build my react native app into apk and it came out this error
I tried the command in vscode terminal eas build -p android
and it came out like this. Please help me fix this. and i usually build my apk app successfully but dk why this time it has this error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
